# bash - Can local variable assignment return false?

Tags: bash, variables

Say I have the following code where `is_wednesday` is a function that returns 0 on Wednesdays and 1 on other days.

```
print_wednesday() {
    is_wednesday && local WEDNESDAY="Yes!" || local WEDNESDAY="No!"
    echo "Is today Wednesday? $WEDNESDAY"
}
```

Is there a way that assigning a value to a local variable would return 1, which in this example would result in printing `Is today Wednesday? No!` on a Wednesday?

Comment: Just use a proper `if then else` and you won't have to worry about obscure failure modes.

Comment: If I replace `is_wednesday` with `true` or `false` then I get the described output. Unfortunately, the question is unclear to me.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Perhaps I didn't choose the best example. The question isn't about the construction, it is purely about return values of variable assignment.

Comment: @Cyrus `A && B || C` is not equivalent to `if A; then B; else C; fi`. If A returns true and B returns false, C is still executed. Therefore, if `local WEDNESDAY="Yes!"` could somehow return false, `local WEDNESDAY="No!"` would be executed and you'd get a `No!` on a Wednesday.

Comment: I don't see any way that assigning a fixed string (here: `Yes!`) to a variable could return a `1` (with `bash`).

Comment: I recommend using lowercase letters for local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a (simple, syntactically correct) local variable assignment can return false.  In particular, it happens if the variable has already been declared `readonly` elsewhere in the code, or declared with `declare -r` outside of a function.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean program demonstrates the issue:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readonly WEDNESDAY='No!'

function test_local_return_value
{
    local WEDNESDAY='Yes!'
    echo "'local' returned $?"
    echo "WEDNESDAY='$WEDNESDAY'"
}

test_local_return_value
```

The output looks like:

```
...: line 7: local: WEDNESDAY: readonly variable
'local' returned 1
WEDNESDAY='No!'
```

This is a serious limitation of `local` because it means that changes elsewhere in a program can break a function that appears to be completely self-contained.  I have seen this happen in practice.  The problem is made worse by the fact that `readonly` creates a global read-only variable even if it is used in a function.  `readonly` needs to be used very carefully.  It shouldn't be used in functions (use `local -r` instead) and it it's best to have a naming convention that ensures `readonly` variable names don't clash with other variable names.

The `readonly` issue is covered in the Bash `man` page (at least for Bash version 4.4).  The section on `local` includes: "The return status is 0 unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable".

Answer (score 0):

> Can local variable assignment return false?

The built-in `local` will:

- return `2` when called with `--help`
- return `2` when called with invalid `-flags`.
- return `1` if not called inside a function
- return `0` ever otherwise
- (or the whole Bash process will terminate, in case of like "out of memory" errors)

Note that variable assignment (I mean, without `local`) will return the exit status of the last process executed. The following will print `No`:

```
true && WEDNESDAY="Yes$(false)" || WEDNESDAY="No"
echo "$WEDNESDAY"
```

> Is there a way that assigning a value to a local variable would return 1, which in this example would result in printing Is today Wednesday? No! on a Wednesday?

No.

---

I would recommend:

- separate `local` from assignment
- do not use `&& ||` chain, always use `if`.
- do not use upper case variables  for local variables.
- and to write the function in the following way:

```
print_wednesday() {
    local wednesday
    if is_wednesday; then
         wednesday="Yes"
    else
         wednesday="No"
    fi
    echo "Is today Wednesday? $wednesday!"
}
```

Comment: `local` will also return 1 if the variable name is invalid, e.g. `local 3=something`